# Использовать setTimeout по клику, перед исчезновением fieldset

Tags: opacity, settimeout, hide, html, javascript

Парни, есть такой вот код:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //show the next fieldset
next_fs.show();

//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        opacity = 1 - now;
        next_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
});
```

});
по клику на ".next" состояние fieldset меняется на display:none с помощью opacity с задержкой 800 милисекунд. Не могу разобраться, как сделать так, чтобы перед исчезновением "fieldset", происходила задержка, функцию setTimeout куда только не пытался воткнуть, Прошу помощи! спасибо!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay/ — не оно?

Comment: да, забыл уточнить, через delay так-же пробовал, но эффект тот же, не выходит.